# Error using ant in pyScriptClassifier install

Tags: java, python, ant, weka, java-8

I'm trying to install pyScriptClassifier from https://github.com/christopher-beckham/weka-pyscript but when I run (everything before this step worked perfectly) (Mac OS X 10.11.6)

```
ant make_package -Dpackage=pyScript
```

this happens

```
...
[javac]     @OptionMetadata(
[javac]      ^
[javac]   symbol:   class OptionMetadata
[javac]   location: class PyScriptFilter
[javac] /Users/eduardoandrade/Desktop/weka-pyscript/src/main/java/weka/filters/pyscript/PyScriptFilter.java:127: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]     @OptionMetadata(
[javac]      ^
[javac]   symbol:   class OptionMetadata
[javac]   location: class PyScriptFilter
[javac] /Users/eduardoandrade/Desktop/weka-pyscript/src/main/java/weka/classifiers/pyscript/PyScriptClassifier.java:209: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[javac]     @Override
[javac]     ^
[javac] /Users/eduardoandrade/Desktop/weka-pyscript/src/main/java/weka/classifiers/pyscript/PyScriptClassifier.java:214: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[javac]     @Override
[javac]     ^
[javac] /Users/eduardoandrade/Desktop/weka-pyscript/src/main/java/weka/classifiers/pyscript/PyScriptClassifier.java:429: warning: [cast] redundant cast to <any>
[javac]                 (List<Object>) m_session.getVariableValueFromPythonAsJson("preds", getDebug());
[javac]                 ^
[javac] /Users/eduardoandrade/Desktop/weka-pyscript/src/main/java/weka/classifiers/pyscript/PyScriptClassifier.java:434: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
[javac]                 List<Double> probsForThisInstance = (List<Double>) vector;
[javac]                                                                    ^
[javac]   required: List<Double>
[javac]   found:    Object

BUILD FAILED
/Users/eduardoandrade/Desktop/weka-pyscript/build.xml:62: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

The command

```
javac -version
```

returns

```
javac 1.8.0_73
```

My env JAVA_HOME variable seems to be ok. Any suggestions? Thank you.

EDITED:

build.xml

```
    <!-- Compile the java code from ${src}/weka into ${build}/classes -->
  <target name="compile" depends="init_compile" 
   description="Compile package and deposit class files in build/classes">
    <javac sourcepath="" srcdir="${src}"
      fork="yes" memoryMaximumSize="${javac_max_memory}"
      destdir="${build}/classes"
      optimize="${optimization}"
      debug="${debug}"
      deprecation="${deprecation}"
      source="1.6" target="1.6">
```

Comment: You need the check the classpath while making the build.

Comment: I did: export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/Users/eduardoandrade/wekafiles/packages/wekaPython/wekaPython1.0.2.jar but got the same error

Comment: No, it needs to be included in the task where `classpath` is passed.

Comment: from build.sh? I'm confused

Comment: You might be running build.xml?